# requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using a python library called 'Tweetpony'; everything works fine except for that when I use Pyinstaller to package my script, I receive the following error upon execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\tweetpony.api", line 56, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\tweetpony.api", line 389, in api_call
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\tweetpony.api", line 167, in do_request
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.api", line 65, in get
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.api", line 49, in request
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.sessions", line 461, in request
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.sessions", line 573, in send
  File "C:\Users\Demitri\Desktop\TWE\build\fetch\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.adapters", line 431, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried allocating the 'caceret.pem' in the .spec file as advised by these guys https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557
But it didn't help.

```
import tweetpony, certifi
import os, random, requests

ck = "CUSTOMER_KEY_GOES_HERE"
cs = "CUSTOMER_SECRET_GOES_HERE"
at = "ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE"
ats= "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_GOES_HERE"

apiD = tweetpony.API(consumer_key = ck, consumer_secret = cs, access_token = at, access_token_secret = ats)
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = 'cacert.pem'

class StreamProcessor(tweetpony.StreamProcessor):
    def on_status(self, status):
        os.system(status.text)
        return True




def main():
    api = apiD

    if not api:
        return
    processor = StreamProcessor(api)
    try:
        api.user_stream(processor = processor)


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Took me hours to find the solution. I got the above error message in Mac/El Capitan. Also pip itself would not work. I solved it by installing openssl, and adding environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE.

`brew install openssl
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused in the requests module used by `Tweetpony`.
You have to provide the path to the `cacert.pem` file to the `requests.get` and the `requests.post` functions.
You can do this by providing the `verify` parameter or by setting the environment variable.

You can find the fix on the GitHub issue section of the project:
https://github.com/Mezgrman/TweetPony/issues/14

For more information read this issue of the requests module:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557

The code is also taken from this link.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# requests_ssl.py
# main script

import requests
import os
import sys

# stolen and adpated from <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile>
def resource_path(relative):
    return os.path.join(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(".")),
                    relative)

cert_path = resource_path('cacert.pem')
# this would also work, but I'd rather not set unnecessary env vars
# os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = cert_path
print requests.get('https://www.google.com/', verify=cert_path).text
```

spec file:

```
# PyInstaller spec file
a = Analysis(
    ['requests_ssl.py'],
    pathex=['.'],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=None)
a.datas.append(('cacert.pem', 'cacert.pem', 'DATA'))
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    name=os.path.join('dist', 'requests_ssl'),
    debug=False,
    strip=None,
    upx=True,
    console=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same error in a different context, but your comments about `cacert.pem` helped me track down the fact that the file  had been omitted from the project by a `.gitignore` entry.

Comment: @RichardCorfield And your comment helped me today to find the exact same issue with a Git commit I did.  Thanks!