# How to cx Freeze Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, cx-freeze, boto3

I created this simple python program that sends a message to SQS and then retrieves it.  It works using python 2.7.11.

```
import boto3 
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='some-que-name')
queue.send_message(MessageBody='{"phrase": "It\'s the end of the world    as we know it" }' )
for message in queue.receive_messages():
    print message.body
```

I then cxFreeze it with this script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_mods = []

excludes = ['tkinter', 'cltk']

buildOptions = dict(packages=[], excludes=excludes, includes=include_mods)


executables = [
     Executable('./frozen_boto_3_test.py', 'Console')
]

setup(name='Boto3FrozenTest',
  version='1',
  description='A test to make sure boto3 is working well when frozen',
  options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
  executables=executables)
```

I then get this error when I try to run the frozen code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "./frozen_boto_3_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 25, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six.moves import configparser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
```

In addition to this problem, the library seem to dynamically load services that are not s3, dynamo, or one other service.

Is there a recipe to freezing boto3  ?

Comment: Are you open to using other packages to freeze?

Comment: Not really.  What do you have in mind ?

Comment: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows that a hidden (dynamic) import is taking place. If you include the module it is looking for (ConfigParser) in the list of modules you tell cx_Freeze to include, it should work. You may have to do this multiple times.

```
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("MyScript.py")]
includes = ["ConfigParser"]
buildOptions = dict(includes = includes)
cx_Freeze.setup(name, description, options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables = executables)
```

Once you have a working program, you can also do this instead of manipulating your specific setup.py. You can add an entry into the cx_Freeze.hooks module that looks something like this:

```
def load_boto3(finder, module):
    finder.IncludeModule("ConfigParser")
```

Include any others that you discover along the way. Then create a pull request or issue over here:

https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Anthony Tuininga

There were a few additional steps that I am posting here:

Added "ConfigParser" and "HTMLParser" as noted by Anthony

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_mods = ["ConfigParser", "HTMLParser"]

excludes = ['tkinter', 'cltk']

buildOptions = dict(packages=[], excludes=excludes, includes=include_mods)


executables = [
     Executable('./frozen_boto_3_test.py', 'Console')
]

setup(name='Boto3FrozenTest',
  version='1',
  description='A test to make sure boto3 is working well when frozen',
  options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
  executables=executables)
```

export AWS_DATA_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/data
from:
[requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726815/requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/cacert.pem

Used lower level code to use sqs:

```
import boto3 

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

queue = sqs.create_queue( QueueName="my-queue" )
sqs.send_message(QueueUrl=queue["QueueUrl"] , MessageBody='{"phrase": "It\'s the end of the world as we know it" }' )
message = sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl=queue["QueueUrl"])
for msg in message['Messages']: 
    print m
```

sg['Body']

After this sqs works for the 'hello world' script posted on the OP